# Chrome lags when I open 2 windows (instances) or more

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, browser

I'm running ubuntu 20.04

Chrome works fine when I open just one window (instance) of it. But it lags when I open 2 windows (instances), especially If I'm using youtube or playing some videos on 1 instance.

Chrome version is 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Note: This problem wasn't occurring before updating to ubuntu 20.04. Also, it works fine when I resize the window (not maximize)

Comment: @Curiouskangaroo I've edited the question hope you'll understand now

Comment: Can you roll back to an older version of chrome?

Comment: Did you come from 18.04? I recall this being an issue in 19.04 and 19.10.

Comment: @EfthimiosChaskaris I updated my system from 19.10 to 20.04

Comment: I opened a bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1137890

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thanks ! This works... but why ?